# Integrating tumblr and sharing video on tumblr's blog

Tags: ios6, ios7

I searched a lot on how to integrate `tumblr` in my ios app - in order to share videos on tumblr's blog. But nothing helped me. I am desperate to know if it is possible to post video on tumblr after integrating? If yes, can someone give me guidance with the code?